# downloading torrent from peers in nodejs

Tags: node.js, torrent, webtorrent

I use this piece of code to download torrent:

```
var torrentStream = require('torrent-stream');

var engine = torrentStream('magnet:?xt=urn:btih:44A91362AFFF802F9058993B109C544ACC6B4813');

engine.on('ready', function(e) {
    engine.files.forEach(function(file) {
        console.log('filename:', file.name);
        var stream = file.createReadStream();
        // stream is readable stream to containing the file content
    });
});
```

This torrent is correctly downloaded by utorrent, but it doesn't work in nodejs (nothing happens). Any ideas why? May be p2p network was not bootstrapped? How can I do this?

Thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of corse there happens nothing, because you dont do anything with the stream in the example.
If you want to save it to a file you can create a write stream:

```
var writeStream = fs.createWriteStream('file2.txt')
stream.pipe(writeStream)
```

or you can use the stream with events:

```
var data = ''
stream.on('data', chunk => {
  data += chunk
})
stream.on('end', () => {
  console.log(data)
})
```

Comment: I expected console.log to work. For some torrents it work. But for this particular one it doesn't.

Comment: Did you mean, there was no output at all (after some seconds the filenames should be logged out) or that there dont come out more? I tried the example together with the writeStream and the movie was downloaded and was playable